# How to compute the spectral norm of this matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, singular-values, hermitian

Consider $$\left\|2\sum_{i<j}L_{ij}+4\sum_i \operatorname{diag}e_i \right\|,$$ where

(1) $L_{ij}=\operatorname{diag}e_i+\operatorname{diag}e_j-e_ie_j^T-e_je_i^T$

(2) $e_i$ denotes $n$-by-$1$ vector with only $i$-th element equals to $1$ and others are $0$

(3) $\operatorname{diag}e_i$ is a $n$-by-$n$ diagonal matrix with only $i$-th diagonal element equals to $1$ and others are $0.$

I am wondering is it possible to obtain the spectral norm of this matrix, or if it is not possible, can we obtain the upper bound of it?

Comment: It looks like your matrix (let's call it $A$) satisfies $A_{jj}=a$, $A_{jk}=b$ ($j\not= k$). In other words $A=a-b + bB$, with $B$ the matrix with all entries equal to $1$. This is a multiple of a projection, so it's straightforward to work out everything.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Could you give a recommendation of summary of spectral norm? I have nothing in mind about which special cases I can directly work out it.

Comment: Your matrix is self-adjoint, so the operator norm is the spectral radius, and a projection has eigenvalues $0,1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making through the terrible notations, we see that
$$M_n:=2\sum_{i<j}L_{ij}+4\sum_{i}\text{diag}\,e_i=(2n+4)I_n-2\,1_n1_n^\top,$$
where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $1_n$ is the $n\times1$ column matrix of $1$'s.

The eigenvectors of the symmetric matrix $M_n$ are the nonzero multiples of $1_n$ and the nonzero vectors orthogonal to $1_n$. The eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $1_n$ is $4$, and eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvectors orthogonal to $1_n$ is $2n+4>4\ge0$. Thus, $\|M_n\|=2n+4$.

Comment: Hi, I got a different result: $2\sum_{i<j}L_{ij}=2(nI_n-11^T)$, $4\text{diag}e_i=4I_n$

Comment: @chloe : Yes, this is now fixed.